# Scipy sparse csr matrix returns nan on 0.0/1.0

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I spotted an unexpected behavior in scipy.sparse.csr_matrix, which seems a bug to me. Can anyone confirm that this is not normal? I am not an expert in sparse structures so I may be misunderstanding proper usage.

```
>>> import scipy.sparse
>>> a=scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((1,1))
>>> b=scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((1,1))
>>> b[0,0]=1
/home/marco/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:730: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
>>> a/b
matrix([[ nan]])
```

On the other hand, numpy properly handles this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.zeros((1,1))
>>> b=np.ones((1,1))
>>> a/b
array([[ 0.]])
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with `(a/b).toarray()` ?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: `(a/b).tolist()` returns `[[nan]]`. `a/b` is of type matrix, so there is no `toarray` or `todense`.

Comment: Submitted a bug report: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6401

Answer (score 2):

For sparse matrix/sparse matrix, the

scipy/sparse/compressed.py

```
    if np.issubdtype(r.dtype, np.inexact):
        # Eldiv leaves entries outside the combined sparsity
        # pattern empty, so they must be filled manually. They are
        # always nan, so that the matrix is completely full.
        out = np.empty(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype)
        out.fill(np.nan)
        r = r.tocoo()
        out[r.row, r.col] = r.data
        out = np.matrix(out)
```

the action is explained in this section.

Try this with slightly larger matrices

```
In [69]: a=sparse.csr_matrix([[1.,0],[0,1]])
In [70]: b=sparse.csr_matrix([[1.,1],[0,1]])
In [72]: (a/b)
Out[72]: 
matrix([[  1.,  nan],
        [ nan,   1.]])
```

So where ever `a` has 0s (no sparse values), the division is `nan`.  It's returning a dense matrix, and filling in `nan`.

Without this code, the sparse element by element division produces a sparse matrix with those 'empty' off diagonal slots.

```
In [73]: a._binopt(b,'_eldiv_')
Out[73]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [74]: a._binopt(b,'_eldiv_').A
Out[74]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

The inverse might be instructive

```
In [76]: b/a
Out[76]: 
matrix([[  1.,  inf],
        [ nan,   1.]])
In [77]: b._binopt(a,'_eldiv_').A
Out[77]: 
array([[  1.,  inf],
       [  0.,   1.]])
```

It looks like the `combined sparsity pattern` is determined by the numerator.  In further test is looks like this after `eliminate_zeros`.

```
In [138]: a1=sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((2,2)))
In [139]: a1
Out[139]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [140]: a1[0,1]=0
In [141]: a1
Out[141]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [142]: a1/b
Out[142]: 
matrix([[  1.,  nan],
        [ inf,   1.]])
```

Comment: Yep, that's the cause of the bug. I've submitted a fix here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/6405